# PHP, SQL, in_array with csv and while loop only retrieving integer

Tags: php, sql, csv

I have searched for similar questions but cannot find the right answer to my specific one. I have a column (data) in my table (table) which contains comma separated values which are id's e.g.

- Row 1= 4,5,45
- Row 2= 5,8,9
- Row 3= 5

I use an in_array function to retrieve the number of occurances for the $data value within the while loop. So I use an sql function to retrieve the number of times a certain value such as '5' occurs in all rows within the while loop.

The issue is that I can only retrieve the `$data` value if it is by itself (i.e. no commas just the integer by itself) so based on my example in the list, I can only retrieve 5 once (row 3). I would like to retrieve the value '5' three times as it appears in all the rows. Here is my code below and any help would be appreciated. The $selectiontext variable is what the user enters from the form.

```
 $sql_frnd_arry_mem1 = mysql_query("SELECT data, id FROM table WHERE    data='$selectiontext'");

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql_frnd_arry_mem1)) { 

$datacheck = $row["data"]; 
$id = $row["id"]; 

}

$frndArryMem1 = explode(",", $frnd_arry_mem1);
if  (($frnd_arry_mem1 !=="") && (!in_array($id, $frndArryMem1))) {echo $id;}
```

Thank you.

Comment: where does `$frndArryMem1` and `$frnd_arry_mem1` come from?

Comment: Hi davogotland, the variable $frndArryMem1 is the expoded function and $frnd_arry_mem1 is the empty variable set to hold the array of csv's and insert the $id variable back into the field. So $frnd_arry_mem1 = "$frnd_arry_mem1,$id"

Comment: This has been answered so many times now... and the No. #1 answer is that you should have properly normalized your data in the first place, and then the problem wouldn't even exist

Comment: Thanks Mark, I'm quite new to database management so I didn't know if this method is the most efficent way. But i'll have a look into normalisation. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

you keep overwriting the variables `$datacheck` and `$id`, leaving you with only the last version of them. move that curly brace down two lines, like this:

```
$sql_frnd_arry_mem1 = mysql_query("SELECT data, id FROM table WHERE    data='$selectiontext'");

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql_frnd_arry_mem1)) { 

    $datacheck = $row["data"]; 
    $id = $row["id"]; 


    $frndArryMem1 = explode(",", $frnd_arry_mem1);
    if  (($frnd_arry_mem1 !=="") && (!in_array($id, $frndArryMem1))) {echo $id;}
}
```

Comment: Hi davogotland, I've tried your method but still only receiving the $id's which are by themselves and not within an array. Alternatively I can retrieve the $id's from the array by modifying the sql statement to use likes such as SELECT data, id FROM table WHERE data='$selectiontext' AND $id like '%newid%'"); The $newid variable is $newid=£id.','; to include the comma. I'm not sure if this is best practice though but it does return all the occurances.

Answer (score 0):

I am not totally sure of your requirements, is not very clear what you intend to do as part of the code is missing.
I assume you want to check each row of a comma separated of a CSV file ($frnd_arry_mem1 being the row) against your data in column data, if any of those comma separated data (not) occurs.
Assuming you are already looping through your CSV, this would be the code (non tested):

NOTE: might be inefficient retrieving data within a loop, if you can do otherwise - but I cant tell as I dont kow the full specs of your script.

If I got the specs wrong please clarify, I will try to help further.

```
$sql = "SELECT data, id
        FROM table
        WHERE data='$selectiontext'";
$sql_frnd_arry_mem1 = mysql_query($sql);
$results = array();
// get values to check
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql_frnd_arry_mem1))
{
  $results[] = array(
                 'datacheck' => $row["data"],
                 'id' => $row["id"],
               ); 
}

foreach ($results as $result)
{
   $frndArryMem1 = explode(",", $frnd_arry_mem1);
   $data = explode(',', $result['datacheck']);
   foreach ($data as $d)
   {
     if  (($frnd_arry_mem1 !=="") && (!in_array($d, $frndArryMem1)))
     {
       echo 'DEBUG: Record #' . $id . ' not found, value:' . $d . '</br>';
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: Hi Uboonto, I've tried your solution and found that it still only retrieves the individual $id's and not the values within a csv. The csv is just a string of id numbers within a column $data. My goal is to extract a specific $id number that occurs in each row within the loop. Currntly I can only retrieve the $id that is by iteslf with no comma separation. I think that the solution is to just normalise the tables as the values $id and $data consist of a many to many relationship. But thank you very much for your help